# Is there any way for using Spark SQL Connector in zeppelin Notebook

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I want to use Spark SQL Connector to read and write data to the SQL Server. As a proof of concept I thought of utilizing zeppelin notebook for performing the task. 
I am able to load the dependency using below line of code in zeppelin :

**%spark.dep**

**z.load("com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark:1.0.2")**

But I am not able to write any of the import statements from that package like

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.query._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy._
```

I am getting error that object azure is not a member of package `com.microsoft`. Do anyone have any idea on why this would be happening?

Comment: what Zeppelin version? and what Spark version there?

Comment: @AlexOtt -- Zeppelin 0.8.2 and Spark Version is 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

try to add this dependency in Interpreter -> Spark -> Dependencies, in this case it's not necessary to use z.load. Restart interpreter after saving artifact.